# How to connect to Azure VM [Linux Type] using service principal details to execute a script(sh) file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-vm

New to PowerShell,

**Context**: Trying to execute a `ShellScript` file reside inside an `AzureVM` (OS Type Linux) from Azure Pipeline using PowerShell.

Script Sample:

```
function getConnectionToRemoteMachine ($AzuresecretValue,$AzureApplicationID,$AzureObjectID,$AzureDirectoryID,$AzureUserName,$AzureSubscriptionID) {
        
        $password =  ConvertTo-SecureString $AzuresecretValue -AsPlainText -Force; 
        $VMResourceGroup = "npd-test-rg01";
        #Connecting to the Azure VM using the Service Principle
        $pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AzureApplicationID, $password);
        Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $AzureDirectoryID -Credential $pscredential | Out-null;
        
        $VMList = Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $VMResourceGroup -Status;

        ForEach($VM in $VMList) {

              if ($VM.Name -eq "npd-test-app01"){
                    Write-Host "Test Machine traced!!!"
                }
              else {
                continue;
              }

        }

}

function triggerShellScript () {
        $AzuresecretValue    = "<AzureSecret>";
        $AzureApplicationID  = "<AzureApplicationID>";
        $AzureObjectID       = "<AzureObjectID>";
        $AzureDirectoryID    = "<AzureDirectoryID>";
        $AzureUserName       = "SVCUSER";
        $AzureSubscriptionID = "<AzureSubscriptionID>";
        getConnectionToRemoteMachine $AzuresecretValue $AzureApplicationID $AzureObjectID $AzureDirectoryID $AzureUserName $AzureSubscriptionID

}

triggerShellScript
```

Able to trace the VM, but don't know how to connect to the machine and trigger the shell script under `/home/TestRun/TriggerTest.sh`

Comment: Hi Rahul, sure let me check if it work then I will sure accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the Shell Script in OS Linux using the Azure Cloud Shell.

**Step 1**: Created a file `script.sh` using command `code script.sh` and pasted the command and save and close editor.

[image]

**Step 2**: use the below command to run the above Script in your VM.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>'
```

[image]

Refernce : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command

Comment: This is trying to execute the test on my local machine and searching for the same script on local.

Comment: No, the srcipt is  uploaded in cloudshell and from there i am executing the script on my Azure VM.

Comment: Please let me know if you are facing any difficulties or doubt to run the script.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion here, I want to execute a shell script on a remote machine from azure devops (specially it will use a agent to run, so here is the drill I can only run that script on the Linux machine, cannot upload it to cloudshell, I tried with `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand` but getting Method 'get_SerializationSettings')

Comment: Type code script.sh in cloudshell it will prompt a editor and just paste your code that you want to execute on Linux Machine then save and close and run the script using the command which i have given in the answer.

Comment: You can watch this video for first 9.30 min : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrL84_5kPx4